# Stream Kafka messages in REST endpoint

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to achieve something with a spring-boot REST service and kafka.  I want to dynamically create a listener to a kafka topic when I receive a REST request, listen to that topic for a period of time, say 10 seconds, filter out messages based on the some value in the message (RecordFilterStrategy I guess?) and stream the messages back to the REST consumer.  Is this possible with Kafka?

I was able to dynamically create a listener to a topic but don't see how to add a record filter to it or how I can stream these back to the caller.

This is how I was dynamically creating a listener to a topic:

```
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer getConsumer(String topic, MessageListener<String, String> listener) {
DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerConfig);

        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topic);
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(listener);


        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
                kafkaConsumerFactory,
                containerProperties);
return container;
}
```

Can someone point me to any documentation on how to achieve this?  I created a GET mapping that can return a Flux of messages but I have no idea how to return the messages on the topic.  I know the below is not correct but the message listener code does get hit.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/v1/messages", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Message> getMessages(@RequestParam String id) {

    MessageListener<String, String> listener = new MessageListener<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> arg0) {
            logger.debug("We got a message:" + arg0);

        }
    };

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer consumer = consumerFactory.getConsumer("mytopic", listener);
    consumer.start();

  //return messages here

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning Flux, maybe it is a good idea to take a look at https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/

and use reactive receiver and which returns flux that you can map

```
Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer, String>> inboundFlux =
Receiver.create(receiverOptions)
        .receive();
```

Or looking at your code you can just pull them all, map and build flux, but that would be blocking.

Answer (score 0):

When using your own `MessageListener` implementation, you have to do the filtering yourself. The `RecordFilterStrategy` is used by the `FilteringMessageListenerAdapter` when using Spring-created listeners for `@RabbitListener` methods.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to an example or documentation on this?  Is it simply that I filter the flux and only ack messages that I want? r.receiverOffset().acknowledge();  Is this the proper way?  Will affect other consumers of this topic?  I am unclear on if I should create specific topics for a customer and only listen to that topic or have a general topic and filter the messages returned based on some identifier in the message.

Comment: An example of what? It depends on your requirements. If you end up filtering 99% of the records it might be better to have a separate topic for each, but only you can decide that. If you use a single topic and each consumer has a unique `group.id` they are independent and will not "affect" each other.  You should ack all messages, even the ones you filter - Kafka does not maintain state for each record, only the last committed offset for a partition. You have to be careful when going async (e.g. with reactor) because the commits might happen out of order.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just need to get a better understanding of how kafka works.